# *ngIf... when data is empty, set disabled=true for mat-checkbox

Tags: html, angular, angular-material, angular-ng-if

I have the following code:

```
<div class="item-container">
  <mat-checkbox class="item">{{contactInfo.privateMobile}}</mat-checkbox>
</div>
```

If `contactInfo.privateMobile` is empty, I don't want the user to be able to check the checkbox.

I have tried something along the lines of: `<mat-checkbox *ngIf={{contactInfo.privateMobile}} === null disabled=true" class="item">{{contactInfo.privateMobile}}</mat-checkbox>`, but that doesn't work or compile. Maybe I need a method in my TypeScript code instead? Not sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't have to use `{{}}` in the `*ngIf`:

```
<div class="item-container">
  <mat-checkbox *ngIf="contactInfo.privateMobile" class="item">{{contactInfo.privateMobile}}</mat-checkbox>
</div>
```

If you wish to just disable it, you could do something like:

```
<div class="item-container">
  <mat-checkbox [disabled]="!contactInfo.privateMobile" class="item">{{contactInfo.privateMobile || '(private mobile unavailable)'}}</mat-checkbox>
</div>
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h1sfoy?file=app%2Fcheckbox-overview-example.html

Answer (score 1):

You can bind attribute like this:

```
[disabled]="contactInfo.privateMobile === null"
```

if that doesn't work, this should:

```
[attr.disabled]="contactInfo.privateMobile === null ? 'disabled' : null"
```

Answer (score 1):

ngIf directive will remove the element from DOM. Use ternary operator in disabled property

```
<mat-checkbox [disabled]=" contactInfo?.privateMobile === null ? true : false">Check me!</mat-checkbox>
```

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ypbktf)